# How to run a configuration script as soon as a Wacom graphics tablet is connected (via USB)?

Tags: 18.04, bash, udev, wacom, automation

I'm using a Wacom graphics tablet under Ubuntu 18.04 (*Kernel:* `4.15.0-72-generic`).

Unfortunately, I cannot configure it using the system settings because it is not recognized properly.

The configuration via `xsetwacom` works, but is not persistent. As soon as I restart the computer or replug the device, the default settings are loaded.

---

I assumed that the easiest solution would be to run a configuration script as soon as the tablet is recognized as a USB device.

According to my understanding, two steps would be necessary to accomplish this:

1. **Create a udev rule**

   I've created a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-config_wacom_intuos.rules` with the content:

   ```
   # "idVendor" and "idProduct" were derived from the output of the lsusb command.
   ACTION=="add" \
   , SUBSYSTEM=="input" \
   , KERNEL=="mouse*" \
   , ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234" \
   , ATTRS{idProduct}=="5678" \
   , RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/config_wacom_intuos.sh >> /var/log/custom_logs/config_wacom_intuos.log 2>&1'"
   ```

   This file has the permissions:

   ```
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    ...
   ```

   (The dictionary `/var/log/custom_logs` were also created by me.)
2. **Create a configuration script**

   I've created a file `/usr/local/bin/config_wacom_intuos.sh` with the content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   #coding:utf8

   # These were the missing statements as suggested by the answer.
   #export DISPLAY=:1
   #export XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority

   echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'`, ShellPID $$, start"

   sleep 1

   if xsetwacom --list devices | grep -q "Wacom Intuos BT"
   then
       main_screen="HEAD-0"
       bezier_args="0 20 80 100"
       positioning_mode="Absolute"
       raw_sample_lvl="9"
       suppress_lvl="10"

       # Maps the graphics tablet to the area of a specified screen (for multiple-screen environments).
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen stylus" MapToOutput "$main_screen"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen eraser" MapToOutput "$main_screen"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen cursor" MapToOutput "$main_screen"

       # Changes the pressure sensitivity.
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen stylus" PressureCurve "$bezier_args"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen eraser" PressureCurve "$bezier_args"

       # Smoothes drawn lines by reducing any quivering.
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen stylus" RawSample "$raw_sample_lvl"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen stylus" Suppress "$suppress_lvl"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen eraser" RawSample "$raw_sample_lvl"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen eraser" Suppress "$suppress_lvl"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen cursor" RawSample "$raw_sample_lvl"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen cursor" Suppress "$suppress_lvl"

       # Specifies the positioning mode ("Absolute" / "Relative")
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen stylus" Mode "$positioning_mode"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen eraser" Mode "$positioning_mode"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen cursor" Mode "$positioning_mode"

       # Assigns actions to the tablet buttons.
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 1 "key +ctrl z -ctrl"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 2 "key +ctrl +shift z -ctrl -shift"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 3 "key 0xffab"
       xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 8 "key 0xffad"

   else
       echo "NO 'WACOM INTUOS BT' DEVICES FOUND."
   fi

   echo "`date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'`, ShellPID $$, end"
   echo -e "---\n"

   exit 0
   ```

   This file has the permissions:

   ```
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    ...
   ```

---

The script works just fine when I executed it manually from the terminal.

It is also executes when I plug in the device. **Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have any effect.**

In addition, the script is executed several times in a row after plugging in the device.
I assume that this behavior occurs because of the udev rule, which is not restrictiv enough.

Can anyone tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: shebang should not contain any space ```#!/bin/bash```

Comment: I've updated the script. Thank you @bac0n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X server tools usually affect only your current session (which is why you have to set them every time).

Since you are running that script in a shell that is not attached to any X session, the tool doesn't have any idea what X session those settings should be changed for (or more precisely, it doesn't have any idea that an X session even exists).

You can manually connect your shell to your current X session, but the solution might be a bit fragile on occasion.

You need to add two variable exports to your script, one for `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`. Those are used for identifying and accessing the correct X session. You can get the appropriate values by running `env` while logged in as your regular user.

In my case, the output looks like the following (parts marked by `[...]` are ommitted):

```
$ env
[...]
XAUTHORITY=/home/tim/.Xauthority
[...]
DISPLAY=:0.0
[...]
```

For those values, I would need to extend the script by the following lines:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/tim/.Xauthority
```

Now, the script should work even while you are the root user.

The udev configuration itself seems fine.

Comment: I've followed your instructions, unfortunately the script still seems not to affect the current session.  
The "what I've tried so far" section of my question was updated, to provide more details about my steps.  
Nevertheless: Thank you!

Comment: Could you add a debug xmessage command (e.g. `xmessage "Test`) as the first command in your script? As soon as this is executed (and the connection is available), a pop-up should appear with the Text you set. This could tell us whether we are still stuck at connecting to the correct X session or whether the issue is somewhere else. Also, you could try to redirect the script's output to a file to check it afterwards: https://superuser.com/questions/1273148/writing-to-a-file-from-a-udev-run-command

Comment: I've implemented your recommendations and added a description of the resulting behavior to the original question. The problem seems to be that the tablet components are not yet registered at the runtime of the script.

Comment: Is the device still not configured correctly, even after udev triggered the script without issues? It appears that the udev rule is triggered by every component that is registered. One possible workaround for the errors would be to check the device list before changing settings. Another way would be to part the script so that we can trigger the sections seperately. This would only work if udev supports the necessary parameters. Could you run `udevinfo <path>` (should be `/dev/input/wacom*`) as outlined here and post the result: http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#udevinfo

Comment: It happens that one of the triggered scripts (and all following) is / are running without errors. If so the device is correctly configured. I assume that this is mainly because of the delay produced by my input.

Comment: At least the script seems to be triggered only once, when I change `ATTRS` to`ATTR` in the udev rule ([Difference between ATTRS and ATTR in udev rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424727/difference-between-attrs-and-attr-in-udev-rules)). But once again the script is not affecting the session (only `Cannot find device 'Wacom Intuos ..'` errors).

Comment: Unfortunately the command `udevinfo` is not installed on my system (nor is it installable via the default ubuntu repositories). I instead ran `udevadm info -q all -n [PATH]`. In order to not increase the length of the question even further, [I posted the result on codedump.io](https://codedump.io/share/KiL183zuDZTk/1/udev-output-for-debugging) (I hope that's ok).

Comment: Not having the script run 18 times is progress. However, I'm starting to get out of ideas. The only thing remaining that I can imagine to be the problem is that the device might not be initialized until after udev ran, so we probably want to try and delay the script. We can't outright `sleep`, since udev might execute those scripts synchronously, so I prepared a modified script that waits in the background and executes the commands after the device appears: https://pastebin.com/NLzfGSvX

Comment: I changed the udev rule so that the script only fires when the kernel `mouse*` is detected. Additionally a sleep command was added to the script.  Now there is a first execution of the script that always fails, but the second one always seems to be successful. Perhaps I later switch to a configuration via `xorg.conf.d` because it seems more reliable. Thank you very much for your help!